# How to set R Studio to break on error in code

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I used R Studio many months ago and had no problems with the debugger, but now it seems that I can't get the IDE to break and show me the environment where an error has occurred. For example, if I have code split over two files in the working directory, along with a folder named **realfolder**.

**`tools.r`**

```
savedata <- function (data, path){
  stopifnot(class(data) == "data.frame")
  write.csv(data, path)
}
```

**`analysis.r`**

```
source("tools.r")

a = c(1,2,3)
b = c(10,20,30)
d = data.frame(a,b)

savedata(d, './realfolder/d.csv') # call A
savedata(1, './realfolder/d.csv') # call B
savedata(d, './fakefolder/d.csv') # call C
```

When I set **Debug -> On Error** to **Break in Code**, and then source *analysis.r*, an error occurs on  the line with **call B**, and the stop is triggered by `stopifnot(class(data) == "data.frame")` as expected. However, the IDE does not pause on that line, but only shows the error message:

```
Error in savedata(1, "./realfolder/d.csv") : 
  class(data) == "data.frame" is not TRUE
```

Calling `traceback()` gives all the relevant info, but I remember it was possible to get a snapshot at the time of the error to see what variables in the environment were causing the issue.

When I set **Debug -> On Error** to **Error Inspector** I get an interactive traceback, but no break. If I comment out the line with **call B**, an error will occur in packaged function from **call C** since **fakefolder** does not exist. In this case, even the error inspector shows only an error message.

Is this normal behavior? Is it possible to get the effect of `browser()` at each point in the traceback when an error has occurred?

I'm using RStudio version 1.2.5033

Comment: what version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: You say "then run tools.r", but presumably you meant "then run "analysis.r", but you don't say how you ran it.   If you click on "Run", that only runs the highlighted lines or the line with the cursor on it, use "Source" instead.

Comment: @user2554330 - You're right, that was a mistake. I was using "Source" on `analysis.r`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting Debug -> On Error to -> Break In Code

[image]

I am using RStudio Desktop 1.2.5033

Comment: I'm also using RStudio Desktop 1.2.5033 and have that the debug set to exactly the way you've shown. I thought it might be some user setting, but I've reinstalled RStudio after following [these instructions](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State) to reset the desktop state.

Comment: Than it is a classically "not reproducible" error - since when I run your two files on my RStudio 1.2.5033 installation it does as expected/defined and 'Break(s) the Code' 'On Error'. So as you already did - most probably resetting your RStudio Desktop would be the best way forward here.

Comment: Thanks anyways @GWD. Could you do me a small favor and show what you see in the Environment (Values and Traceback) window when it breaks? When I followed Data Munger's answer, [this is what I saw](https://i.imgur.com/n0lYObG.png) and it wasn't very useful, since it doesn't show the environment inside of the `savedata` function where the stop is actually called.

Comment: Hi @rovyko, it should all be there you just have to fiddle around a bit in the Environment tab - the drop-down in the left upper corner there should provide you with the possibility to look at the right environment/closure and its elements/objects. Currently (in your screenshot `stopifnot` is selected there -  change that to eg `stop` and then the Environment tab will show you the args etc.

Comment: Got it. I just had to navigate one step back. In this case I had to navigate to step ` 5: analysis.r#10: savedata(d, "./fakefolder/d.csv")` to see the argument values. It works, but it's not as good as the Python traceback unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

put this as the first line of  your script:

```
options(error = utils::recover)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves at least part of the problem. When I include this line at the beginning of and source `analysis.r`, I get an option to stop at `tools.r#2: stopifnot(class(data) == "data.frame")`. However, when I stop there, in the traceback window I can only select from environments of builtin function. I can't actually stop at `tools.r line 2` and inspect the environment state at that point, which is what I would need to debug the function.